# Add event on S3 using CloudFormation - 'bucket already exists' error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a lambda function with a S3 trigger. While executing the templates, I am getting S3 bucket already exist error. There is no any buckets with the same name in my S3 and even in this code I am creating bucket only once but somehow it seems it is creating buckets twice.

Below are the my cloudformation templates.

```
    '''python
    
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  BucketName:
    Type: String
Resources:
  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    DependsOn:
      - ProcessingLambdaPermission
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Ref BucketName
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
          - Event: s3:PutObject:*
            Function: !GetAtt ProcessingLambdaFunction.Arn
            Filter:
              S3Key:
                Rules:
                - Name: suffix
                  Value: .txt

  ProcessingLambdaPermission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      Action: 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
      FunctionName: !Ref ProcessingLambdaFunction
      Principal: s3.amazonaws.com
      SourceArn: 'arn:aws:s3:::hope'
      SourceAccount: !Ref AWS::AccountId

  ProcessingLambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: allowLogging
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - logs:*
              Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
        - PolicyName: getAndDeleteObjects
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: '2012-10-17'
            Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Action:
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:DeleteObject
              Resource:  !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${BucketName}/*'

  ProcessingLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
            import json
            import boto3
            s3 = boto3.client("s3")
            def lambda_handler(event,context):
              print("hello")
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt ProcessingLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Runtime: python2.7
      MemorySize: 512
      Timeout: 120

    '''
```

Comment: An Amazon S3 bucket name is globally unique, and the namespace is shared by all AWS accounts. This means that after a bucket is created, the name of that bucket cannot be used by another AWS account in any AWS Region until the bucket is deleted. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingBucket.html

Comment: thank you. It worked.